# How to omit accessories from SPBluetoothDataType results

Tags: macos, terminal, bluetooth, system-profile

I've dug all over and I can't find an answer to this:
When I run the system_profiler command on a macbook (Catalina) to grep a piece of info, I can't seem to omit all of the SystemInfo-Accessories.
The specific command I'm using:

```
system_profiler -detailLevel full SPBluetoothDataType | grep "LMP Version"
```

And it DOES grep the LMP info I need, but first it hits me with several lines listing all of the bluetooth devices that have ever connected to the system.

Does anyone out there know how to omit the accessories from the results?

[screenshot of terminal with command results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRdG5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem yesterday when trying to query another variable in SPBluetoothDataType. In case you or anyone else needs the answer:

```
system_profiler -detailLevel full SPBluetoothDataType 2>/dev/null | grep "LMP Version"
```

You need to redirect the STDERR to null, and therefore you only get the result you want.